# Where should [site-recommendation] questions go?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Following the creation of Meta.SE, are [site-recommendation](/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) questions still on-topic for Stack Overflow's per-site meta?

I could understand asking a binary "Is question X on-topic for Stack Overflow" on the Stack Overflow meta, but asking generally "where can I ask about question X?" seems like it's not quite on topic for a local meta. If the heart of the question is actually "is X locally on topic here; if not, then where?" then I suppose that's on-topic for a local meta, but then you're asking binary yes/no with an implied follow-up in the "no" case. In that case, is `[site-recommendation]` appropriate?

It seems obvious that "where can I ask questions about cat food?" is not on-topic for Stack Overflow's meta. Is "where can I ask questions about Emacs?" on-topic purely because there's a non-trivial possibility that the answer is Stack Overflow?

Should we be mass-migrating `[site-recommendation]` to Meta.SE, or is there some case where they're more appropriate to local metas? It's entirely possible I don't fully understand the appropriate role of per-site metas in this case.

Comment: FWIW [site-rec](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-rec) tag seems to be considered okay at Programmers per-site-meta

Comment: I'd like to ask a question about an old joke, but it doesn't seem like that one is on here.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Any site-recommendation question that involves code or programming can be asked here.

If that causes too much cognitive dissonance for you, simply read the question as "Is this question suitable for Stack Overflow, or should I ask it somewhere else?"

Comment: I'm a little bit surprised because I expected those type of question to be seen in the same context as [tag:bug]. You don't need to post on MSE to report a network-wide bug so why would you need to post on MSE if you're an active user on SO if you only want to know where to post your question that won't fit on SO?

Comment: Questions about which English site to ask a general question about grammar are clearly off-topic here, because they don't have anything to do with SO.  In general, we don't want to be in the business here of steering *everyone* who gets lost to the correct site *network-wide.* Bugs can be posted on any meta site because SE corporate monitors the bug report tag network-wide.