# I asked for question migration two weeks ago, are migrate flags allowed on Meta.SO?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, meta

I probably should've just deleted [the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321685/607407) and post it on Meta.SE. But I thought deleting questions should be only used when the question is invalid.

So I flagged the question:

[image: image description]

I guess that was wrong move since the question wasn't migrated. Should I just delete the question without bothering the mods next time? What about the question I already asked? Delete and ask on Meta.SE? Keep and add Meta.SE link in the question?

Comment: related: [Where should \[site-recommendation\] questions go?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/275829/839601) Per my reading of the answer there MSE is the correct migration target in case of control system engineering (as opposed to SO meta, meaning you couldn't vote to migrate it here)